# How to rotate Annotations when converting HDF5 files to dm3?

Tags: dm-script

I am working on converting Velox file (HDF5) to .dm3 file using Tore Niermann's plugin (gms_plugin_hdf5) to read string. Annotations on HDF5 file also need to transfer to .dm3 file. HDF5 file maybe rotate in any angle. But the position coordinate of annotation read from hdf5 file is corresponding to images without rotating.
I found that the annotations didn't move with rotating images. I had to re-calculate the position coordinate for every annotation. It isn't convenient for annotations such as box or oval. And I need to extract maximum area when rotating images. So the image size will change with rotation angle. So is there better solutions for rotating the annotations？ Thanks.
Here is a sample function from my script. I didn't attach all because it's quite long.

```
image GetAnnotations(Taggroup names, string filename, string name, Taggroup Annotations, Image VeloxImg, number Angle)
{
number i, j, imagex, imagey, xscale, yscale
String Displaypath, AnnotationStr, DisplayStr, units
taggroup attr = NewTagList()
getsize(VeloxImg, imagex, imagey)
number centerx=imagex/2
number centery=imagey/2
getscale(veloximg, xscale, yscale)
units=getunitstring(veloximg)
component imgdisp=imagegetimagedisplay(VeloxImg, 0)
    For (j=0; j<TagGroupCountTags(Annotations); ++j)
        {
        TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsString(Annotations, j, AnnotationStr)
        string AnnotPath=h5_read_string_dataset(filename, AnnotationStr)
        string AnnotDataPath=GetValueFromLongStr(AnnotPath, "dataPath\": \"", "\"")
        AnnotDataPath=ReplaceStr(AnnotDataPath, "\\/", "\/")
        string AnnotLabel=GetValueFromLongStr(AnnotPath, "label\": \"", "\"")
        string AnnotDrawPath=h5_read_string_dataset(filename, AnnotDataPath)
        image img := RealImage( "", 4, 1, 1 )
        TagGroup AnnoTag=alloc(MetaStr2TagGroup).ParseText2ImageTag(AnnotDrawPath, img )
        deleteimage(img)
        string AnnotDrawType=TagGroupGetTagLabel(AnnoTag,0)
        //AnnoTag.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow( "AnnotationsTag", 0 )
        
        if (AnnotDrawType=="arrow")
        {
        number p1_x,p1_y,p2_x,p2_y
        TagGroupGetTagAsNumber(AnnoTag, "arrow:p1:x", p1_x)
        TagGroupGetTagAsNumber(AnnoTag, "arrow:p1:y", p1_y)
        TagGroupGetTagAsNumber(AnnoTag, "arrow:p2:x", p2_x)
        TagGroupGetTagAsNumber(AnnoTag, "arrow:p2:y", p2_y)
        //VeloxImg.CreateArrowAnnotation( p1y, p1x, p2y, p2x )
        number p1_x_new=(p1_x-0.5)*cos(Angle)+(p1_y-0.5)*sin(Angle)+0.5
        number p1_y_new=-(p1_x-0.5)*sin(Angle)+(p1_y-0.5)*cos(Angle)+0.5
        number p2_x_new=(p2_x-0.5)*cos(Angle)+(p2_y-0.5)*sin(Angle)+0.5
        number p2_y_new=-(p2_x-0.5)*sin(Angle)+(p2_y-0.5)*cos(Angle)+0.5
        result(p1_x+" "+p1_y+" new "+p1_x_new+" "+p2_y_new+"\n")
        
        component arrowAnno=newarrowannotation(p1_y_new*imagey, p1_x_new*imagex, p2_y_new*imagey, p2_x_new*imagex)
        arrowAnno.ComponentSetForegroundColor( 1, 0 , 0 )
        arrowAnno.ComponentSetDrawingMode( 2 )
        imgdisp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd( arrowAnno )
        }
```

Comment: HDF5 is a directly supported file-format in GMS 3.5 - but I don't think this solves your immediate problem. (As GMS does not support "rotation" of image-objects without resampling them to a new, screen-axis aligned grid.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly answering your question, but maybe nevertheless of interest to you:
While GMS does not support the rotation of annotations (Rect, Oval, Text, ImageDisplay...) it does support a rotation property for ROIs. So maybe you can just use rect-ROIs and oval-ROIs instead of annotations in your application.
Example (never mind, that I did the shift-computation wrongly):

```c
image test := realImage("Test",4,512,512)
test= abs(sin(6*PI()*icol/iwidth))*abs(cos(4*PI()*irow/iheight*iradius/150))
test.showimage()
imageDisplay disp = test.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
ROI box = NewROI()
box.RoiSetRectangle(46,88,338,343)
box.RoiSetVolatile(0)
ROI oval = NewROI()
oval.ROISetOval(221,226,287,254)
oval.RoiSetVolatile(0)
disp.ImageDisplayAddROI(box)
disp.ImageDisplayAddROI(oval)


number rot_deg = 8
image rot := test.rotate( pi()/180*rot_deg)
rot.ShowImage()
imageDisplay disp_rot = rot.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
ROI box_rot = box.ROIClone()
ROI oval_rot = oval.ROIClone()
disp_rot.ImageDisplayAddROI(box_rot)
disp_rot.ImageDisplayAddROI(oval_rot)

number shift_x = (rot.ImageGetDimensionSize(0)-test.ImageGetDimensionSize(0)) / 2
number shift_y = (rot.ImageGetDimensionSize(1)-test.ImageGetDimensionSize(1)) / 2

number t,l,b,r
box_rot.ROIGetRectangle(t,l,b,r)
box_rot.ROISetRectangle(t+shift_y,l+shift_x,b+shift_y,r+shift_x)

oval_rot.ROIGetOval(t,l,b,r)
oval_rot.ROISetOval(t+shift_y,l+shift_x,b+shift_y,r+shift_x)

box_rot.ROISetRotationAngle( rot_deg )
oval_rot.ROISetRotationAngle( rot_deg )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is  what I need. Although the rotation only supports Rect-ROI and Oval-ROI, I will use them instead of annotations.  And I will re-computed the coordinate system for other annotations. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, then your source data (HDF5) stores the image (2D array?) plus a rotation angle, but the annotations in the coordinate system of the (not rotated) image? How is the source-data displayed in the original software then? (Is it showing a rotated rectangle-image?)

GMS does not support rotating imagesDisplays (as objects) and consequently also not rotations of annotations. The coordinates systems are always screen-axis aligned orthogonal. Hence the need for interpolation when "rotating" images. The data values are re-computed for the new grid.

If you don't need the annotations to be adjustable after your input, one potential thing you could do would be to create an "as displayed" image after import prior rotation, and then rotate the image with the annotations "burnt in".
This is obviously only good for creating "final display images" though.

```c
image before := realImage("Test",4,512,512)
before = abs(sin(6*PI()*icol/iwidth))*abs(cos(4*PI()*irow/iheight*iradius/150))

before.showimage()
before.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ComponentAddChildAtEnd(NewArrowAnnotation(30,80,60,430))
before.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ComponentAddChildAtEnd(NewArrowAnnotation(30,80,206,240))
before.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ComponentAddChildAtEnd(NewOvalAnnotation(206,220,300,256))


// Create as-displayed image
Number t,l,b,r,ofx,ofy,scx,scy
before.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument().ImageDocumentGetViewExtent(t,l,b,r)
before.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument().ImageDocumentGetViewToWindowTransform(ofx,ofy,scx,scy)
image asShown := before.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument().ImageDocumentCreateRGBImageFromDocument(round((r-l)*scx),round((b-t)*scy),0,0)
asShown.ShowImage()

number angle_deg = 8
image rotated := asShown.Rotate( angle_deg/180*PI() )
rotated.ShowImage()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You clearly understand my problems and sorry for the unclear description. This is a brilliant way. But the rotation angle may be 180° in real cases. So the text will not show correctly in that cases. So coordinate system transformations are more suitable for me. Thanks a lot.